# How to show SpagoBI OLAP cube in spagobi user login?

Tags: xml, business-intelligence

I have been working with SpagoBI and I've created the sample OLAP cube using our own xml schema. It works fine with the spagobi admin login. But when I go to log in as a spagobi user it throws an error: *Error while getting template as a XML document*. I think this indicates it is not able to retrieve the xml schema. I have granted all possible permissions to that particular user. I'm not sure what troubleshooting steps to take next or how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is getting this message:
"Error while getting template as a XML document".

It could be a "permissions" issue, 
If the problem is that you can run the document 
as admin user but  not as regular user

the problem may be solved in this way

in spagobi (in your browser) 
go to Document Details (Detalles del Documento)
and change the 
state (estado) 
from Development (Desarrollo)
to Released (publicado)